# Is my "design pattern" for asynchronous methods good?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, asynchronous

When I'm writing a class which contains methods that are probably going to be executed on another thread, then I prepare my class for async usage.
I add events to the class as the following:
methodProgressChanged
methodCompleted

In the method(s), before every sub-operation (for example, iterations) I raise the ProgressChanged event with a custom EventArgs class. This custom class contains info about what sub-operation is beginning now, and what the result of the previous sub-operation was.

So executing the method on another thread is not the method's task, it's just reporting the progress.

And of course, when I execute my method, the caller takes care of subscriptions to the events.

Is this idea acceptable, or should I forgot it totally?

Comment: I think some code samples would certainly help in determining what is **good**. I can tell you that detecting a pattern and taking advantage of the pattern are definitely good. It's what you do within that pattern than can counter the benefits. So, is there any way you could give a bit more to go on? Without seeing more of a sample, it really will be very difficult to provide any feedback.

Comment: @IAbstract I have cooked it up because I don't want to block the UI while doing sweaty work. For example, I would use this pattern to get the rows from a DbDataReader, and immediately add the result to a ListView using the ProgressChanged event. The user will be happy, because while loading the records into the listview, he can browse, edit, delete the loaded records, and he also can cancel the operation. Or, while starting up the app, a small dialog appears, which informs the user what is being loaded at the moment, and if he wants to, he can cancel it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in .NET 4.0, I would recommend looking into Task and Task to encapsulate your async functionality.  Then you could return a Task from the method you want to be a like so:

```
public Task<MyClass> Foo()
{
    return new Task<MyClass>(() => 
    {
         ReportProgress();
         DoSubOperation1();
         ReportProgress();
         DoSubOperation2();
         // ...
         return myClass;
    });
}
```

If you don't care about a return type, you can use the non-generic task.  Then, when you call Foo(), you can call ContinueWith on the Task to give it a method to call once the Task completes.

If you want progress, you will need to keep your progress event because that's custom to the method that you're writing.

But overall, Task is a nice encapsulation for async functionality that keeps you from having to repeat the same MyMethod() MyMethodCompleted() pattern over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable idea, but I think it might be overkill, just because you're making assumptions that your events will be subscribed to.  That said, I don't think it really causes too many problems, so long as your event subscribers behave properly; it's just that doing this incurs a little bit of overhead that may be wasted effort.  That said, I don't really see anything wrong with it other than the (small) amount of (potentially unfruitful) time put into adding / raising the events.

Comment: The OP could always check for `GetInvocationList().Count > 0` or something ... might be helpful. IMO, though, I think the loss in performance is probably miniscule. Objects that provide events should have the assumption that they will be subscribed to - otherwise, what is the point of having them? That is why, before the event is even triggered, `(myEventHandler != null)` is the first check.

Comment: IAbstract: I'm not at all concerned about runtime performance; I was just concerned that implementing this in the code might cause some level of code bloat, and might increase development time.  The amount of added bloat / development time would be small however, I suspect, so it's really up to the OP to determine whether or not it's worth it for them.